# Flutter did future widget didnt update screen ? i need to update data when its updated

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array which i set as a class like this

```
class FilterArray {
  static var FilterArrayData = [];
}
```

I am simply adding the values in an array. Issue is i am calling this array in a page when array is null. Then on next Page i am adding values in array. Now issue is when i come back in previous page the array is still null. I need to refresh page for this. Which i dont want thats why i use FutureWidget i though from Future widget when array update it will also update in my screen but thats not working. Need to know what can i do for this here i need to update data when array is update so it can show in a Future Widget.

This is my total code

```
  class _SearchPgState extends State<SearchPg> {
  Future getData() async {
    var result = FilterArray.FilterArrayData;
    if (result.length != 0) {
      return result;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(FilterArray.FilterArrayData);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3.0),
            child: Center(
              child: TextField(
                onTap: () => Get.to(SearchPgExtra()),
                readOnly: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: tr('search.search'),
                  alignLabelWithHint: true,
                  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              FlutterIcons.sort_descending_mco,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
            onPressed: navigateToSortPage,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              FlutterIcons.filter_fea,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
            onPressed: navigateToFilterPage,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(), // async work

        builder: (context, projectSnap) {
          print(projectSnap.data);

          if (projectSnap.hasData) {
            return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              itemCount: projectSnap.data.length,
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
              mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var product = projectSnap.data[0][index];
                return FadeInAnimation(
                  index,
                  child: ProductCard2(
                    product: product,
                    isHorizontalList: false,
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/search.png',
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  Text(
                    'search.title',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                  ).tr(),
                  SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  Text(
                    'search.subtitle',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                  ).tr(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

In start array is null then ill add values in array then comeback nothing change then i reload the screen then its working fine.

This is the how i am adding array

```
RangeSlider(
  values: _currentRangeValues,
  min: 0,
  max: 10000,
  divisions: 10,
  labels: RangeLabels(
    _currentRangeValues.start.round().toString(),
    _currentRangeValues.end.round().toString(),
  ),
  onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
    setState(() {
      _currentRangeValues = values;
      //print(_currentRangeValues);

    });
    var data = searchArray.searchArrayData;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var current = data[i];

      if(current['Price'] >= _currentRangeValues.start && current['Price'] <= _currentRangeValues.end){
        print(data);
        FilterArray.FilterArrayData.add(data);

      }
    }
  },
),
```

when data add to FilterArrayData  ill go back on Page array on that page not updating so then i change the page and comeback again in SearchPg then i can see data

Comment: which code show the come back code?

Comment: @JohnJoe its simple screen screen i just add the array and come back. But its not updaing the array i need to refresh the app then i can see data in snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Don't do your validation with the length of your array. It is like trying to do a validation with something that doesn't existe yet. Instead of that, try using

```
 if(snapshot.hasData)

       { return ... ; }
```

then, after that, now you can do another validation, for instance, sometimes what you receive is data, but an empty array. There is where I would place the other two options. Remember, inside of the first if.

```
 if(array.isNotEmpty)

       { return ... ; }
```

and

```
 else


       { return ... ; }
```

After the first if, then you can now also validate, what will happen if you didn't receive data at all. Simply with an else.

```
 else 

       { return ... ; }
```

In summary: use one first validation with hasData and then, inside of that, decide what to do with the received information. Outside all that, decide what to do if you didn't receive any information at all.

Comment: I have updated my code now. But still when array update its not updating on screen or snapshot dont have data till i refresh the app

Comment: are you using part of the data that you receive, outside the futurebuilder? If so, that shouldn't be the case. You need to remember, you can't render anything before you get the data. And that is what futurebuilder is for.

Answer (score 0):

Such cases are faced by new developers often. The best way to deal with it is state management packages like [Provider, Bloc, etc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options). Visit the link and you will find all the relevant packages. Personally, I have used Provider a lot. Bloc is also a good option. A lot of people use it. But I haven't had the chance to use it. Riverpod is an up and coming package. But it still requires a lot of fixing.